# Can not horizontally align the div with text-align?

Tags: html, css

I want align the div horizontally.

```css
.d1 {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: justify;
}

.d1::after {
  content: '';
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dd {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div class="dd">aa</div>
  <div class="dd">bb</div>
</div>
```

but it can not justify the div and align is left. Why?

Comment: Curious, why is font size set to 0?

Comment: no matter set the size or not .it still align to left not jsutify.@Mech

Comment: your code works fine, check the snippet I made

Answer (score 0):

Please specify how you want to align the div's along the horizontal axis.
For now, I have aligned them adjacent to each other on the left side.

```
<div class="d1">
  <div class="dd">aa</div>
  <div class="dd">bb</div>
</div>

.d1 {
 display: flex;
}
.dd{
  margin: 1rem; //to provide space in between
}
```